# How to get specific columns in Laravel Eloquent with pagination?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7, laravel-pagination

I use this table schema:

```
Schema::create('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 255)->default('');
    $table->text('html')->nullable();
    $table->text('json')->nullable();

    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

This is the model:

```
class Form extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'html',
        'json'
    ];

    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
}
```

And in the controller I want to show a list of all items of model but only the `id` and `name` fileds. Now I use this, but it show all not hidden fields:

```
public function index() {
    return Form::->paginate(100);
}
```

This function is only for the list of forms names. But here is the second one for show a form datas for modify:

```
public function show(string $id) {
    $item = Form::findOrFail($id);

    return response()->json($item);
}
```

Of course this last one function needs to be show all fields (id, name, html and json too).

Is there any best practice to show only fields what I needed in the `index()` function using with `paginate()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i am not wrong then hopefully you can do it something like this for getting specific columns along with pagination:

```
return Form::paginate(100,['id','name',.....]);
```

Comment: This one is the most simplier solution. Thank you!

Comment: How can you get columns in nested relationships using this method ?

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, what you want to do is create a collection of the `Form` object where only the `id` and the `name` fields are actually retrieved on the index overview.

You can do that pretty easily by creating a new collection instance in your controller:

```
public function index() {
   // use the Eloquent select() function
   $forms = Form::select('id', 'name')->paginate(100);
   return $forms;
}
```

I would personally put that collection in a repository pattern to make it more easily cacheable. [Here's a nice canonical reference](https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce) to repository patterns in Laravel.

In your show function on your controller you needn't change a thing, considering the ID is still the same.

For future reference, remember that the paginate method paginates only the collection it is called on, and not everything related to a specific model or anything other than that collection. Thus, if you create a new collection in any way, and call the paginate method on that new collection, only whatever is inside that will be paginated. It's pretty powerful stuff! [Here's the documentation reference.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination)

Comment: `Form::all('id', 'name')->paginate(100)` is not working because of this: `Collection::paginate does not exist`, but the `Form::select()` version working fine. Thank you!

Comment: Ah that's odd, I thought all Eloquent functions should be able to paginate. Removed it anyway.